# Count lines and print with less quantity

Tags: python

```
class Line(models.Model):
    _name = "line"

line1.quantity = 5
line2.quantity = 8
line3.quantity = 3

def count_line(self):
    for line in self:
        # i need to count all lines and print that line in the end #that has least quantity.
```

It's more like a pseudo code , i just want to know logic how to do this.

Comment: I _wish_ this was pseudocode.

Comment: Is it class or what? Write please a simple example. And output that you will expect.

Comment: updated my question hope it help

Comment: What are the limits on the `quantity` property--is it always nonnegative?

Comment: it can be negative

Comment: Hello Chaban, What happens when you try to run this code? My best guess is that  it wont run as written unless `models.Model` does more then I think it does.

Comment: I simplified this code, because python is modified for my framework and it can be really complicated to understand what i want. for me important is just a logic how to compare all lines and find out whitch one is with lesser quantity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you give no restrictions on the `quantity` property, this code should handle the edge cases. Note that it prints the line with the smallest `quantity`, as desired, and returns the total number of lines. If there are no lines, the printout is `None` and the number `0` is returned. If there is a lower limit to `quantity`, the code could be simplified.

```
def count_line(self):
    """Count all lines, print that line in the end that has least
    quantity, and return the number of lines."""
    counter = 0
    result = None
    for counter, line in enumerate(self):
        if result is None or result.quantity > line.quantity:
            result = line
    print(result)
    return counter
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list with all your lines you can do:

```
line_list.sort(key=lambda x: x.quantity, reverse=False)
less_quantity = line_list[0].quantity
```